# Add conditional data in Laravel's Transformer

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say that I have a UserTransformer. It is being used to show the data in the user profile (private) and also in the User listing.
Now I want to conditionally return that data. If I'm the user, then return all. If I'm not, just return the basic data.
What's the proper way to do this? Can I achieve this with a conditional inside an include function and add the sensitive_data if the user that is requesting is the owner?

Comment: you can probably use the auth class and cross check it with the user profile, then a simple if else

Comment: Yes that was my first thought, but after I check if the Auth::User->id is what would be the way to include the sensitive_data array to the transformer array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Fractal, something like this:

```php
class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(User $user)
    {
        $data = [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
        ];

        if (Auth::id() === $user->id) {
          $data = array_merge($data, User::getSensitiveData($user));
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So the method getSensitiveData should be in the model and return the data as a collection ?

Comment: `array_merge()` would expect an array not a collection

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. Your answer works like a charm! Thank you